# ¿Por que mi objeto se convierte de manera erronea? C#

Tags: c#, socket, byte

tengo este codigo, lo que hace es enviar un objeto a travez de socket pero para ello tengo que convertirlo en una rreglo de bytes[] con este codigo lo convierto:

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Lo envio:

```
Input input = new Input()
                {
                    type = (int)InputType.Mouse,
                    u = new InputUnion()
                    {
                        mi = new MouseInput()
                        {
                            dwFlags = (int)MouseEventF.RightDown,
                            mouseData = 0,
                            dx = 0,
                            dy = 0,
                            dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
                            time = 0
                        }
                    }
                };
                byte[] buffer = ObjectToByteArray(input);
                _UdpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length);
```

Ahora tenemos que convertirlo de nuevo al tipo Input con este codigo:

```
    private object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes, Type type)
    {
        var bytes = arrBytes;
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(arrBytes.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, arrBytes.Length);
        var @object = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, type);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return @object;
    }
```

Pero el problema esta en que no lo convierte correctamente ya que cuando lo convierte de nuevo a un objeto las propiedades se mezclan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el flag deberia tener el 8 pero lo tiene el time.

Esto a que se debe?, como puedo solucionarlo??

PD. estas son mis clases las cuales quiero convertir en Byte[]

```
 [Serializable]
internal static class Win32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, Input[] pInputs, int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
}

[Serializable]
public struct KeyboardInput
{
    public ushort wVk;
    public ushort wScan;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[Serializable]
public struct MouseInput
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[Serializable]
public struct InputUnion
{
    public MouseInput mi;
    public KeyboardInput ki;
}
[Serializable]
public struct Input
{
    public int type;
    public InputUnion u;
}
[Serializable]
public enum InputType
{
    Mouse = 0,
    Keyboard = 1
}
[Serializable]
public enum KeyEventF
{
    KeyDown = 0x0000,
    ExtendedKey = 0x0001,
    KeyUp = 0x0002,
    Unicode = 0x0004,
    Scancode = 0x0008
}
[Serializable]
public enum MouseEventF
{
    Absolute = 0x8000,
    HWheel = 0x01000,
    Move = 0x0001,
    MoveNoCoalesce = 0x2000,
    LeftDown = 0x0002,
    LeftUp = 0x0004,
    RightDown = 0x0008,
    RightUp = 0x0010,
    MiddleDown = 0x0020,
    MiddleUp = 0x0040,
    VirtualDesk = 0x4000,
    Wheel = 0x0800,
    XDown = 0x0080,
    XUp = 0x0100
}
```

Comment: ¿Alguna razón específica por la que tengas que serializar y deserializar de esa manera tan extraña? ¿No puedes usar simplemente [algo como esto](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jZPUGm)? Basicamente convierto el objeto a bytes con `JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(obj)` y luego lo vuelvo a convertir en objeto del tipo específico con `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bytes);`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Hola, gracias por responder, he probado tu metodo y me sale una excepcion al deserializar el objeto que dice: ''0x00' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Aparte de que al convertirlo solo me salen { } cuando el objeto no esta vacio

Comment: Si, de hecho, un rato despues de que te puse el comentario, me di cuenta que lo que estabas serializando eran estructuras, y me temo que eso no estaba soportado por el JsonSerializer. Esperaba un error como ese o algo vacío. Viendo tus objetos, entiendo por qué tu código lucía así.